# cannot access resources of .jar file using Spring Boot Maven Plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, executable-jar

One libary i've been using stores its templates in `resources/vc-templates/*.json`. Accessing the templates with this code:

```
        checkNotNull(resource) { "Cannot find resource path: $resourcePath" }

        log.debug { "Loading templates from: $resource" }

        when {
            File(resource.file).isDirectory ->
                File(resource.file).walk().filter { it.isFile }.map {
                    (it.relativeTo(File(resource.file)).parent?.let { "$it/" } ?: "") + it.nameWithoutExtension
                }.toList()

            else -> {
                FileSystems.newFileSystem(resource.toURI(), emptyMap<String, String>()).use { fs ->
                    Files.walk(fs.getPath(resourcePath))
                        .filter { it.isRegularFile() }
                        .map {
                            (Path.of(it.toString()).relativeTo(Path.of(resourcePath)).parent?.let { "$it/" } ?: "") + it.nameWithoutExtension
                        }.toList()
                }
            }
        }
```

It's working fine with `./mvnw spring-boot:run`. But as I want to deploy it as .jar using `./mvnw clean package`, I get this error, caused by not finding the /vc-templates folder.

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /vc-templates
        at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.readAttributes(ZipPath.java:769) ~[jdk.zipfs:na]
        at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.readAttributes(ZipPath.java:777) ~[jdk.zipfs:na]
        at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:276) ~[jdk.zipfs:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1851) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:220) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:277) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:323) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.<init>(FileTreeIterator.java:71) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walk(Files.java:3918) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walk(Files.java:3973) ~[na:na]
        at id.walt.credentials.w3c.templates.VcTemplateService$resourceWalk$1.invoke(VcTemplateService.kt:124) ~[waltid-ssikit-1.2306281832.0.jar!/:na]
        at id.walt.credentials.w3c.templates.VcTemplateService$resourceWalk$1.invoke(VcTemplateService.kt:109) ~[waltid-ssikit-1.2306281832.0.jar!/:na]
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/:1.8.22-release-407(1.8.22)]
        at id.walt.credentials.w3c.templates.VcTemplateService.listResources(VcTemplateService.kt:134) ~[waltid-ssikit-1.2306281832.0.jar!/:na]
        at id.walt.credentials.w3c.templates.VcTemplateService.listTemplates(VcTemplateService.kt:149) ~[waltid-ssikit-1.2306281832.0.jar!/:na]
```

Interestingly the code above prints out:
`Loading templates from: jar:file:/Path/to/*.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/vc-templates`

I was wondering about the exclamation mark on classes. Could it be that the folder cannot be found because of this?
Is there a way around this? How does javaClass.getResource() work for jar-files?

There is also a *.jar.original generated, which is the maven version before repackage goal. I tried executing this: `no main manifest attribute, in *.jar.original`

Comment: A file is a resource on the filesystem. A file packed in a jar isn't a physical resource. So this code doesn't work from within a jar. This has nothing to do with Spring but on the definition of a file that `java.io.File` keeps.

Comment: @M.Deinum thats quite interesting. Any suggestions to replace it?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here. As you are using Spring you should prbably be using the resource loading mechanism from spring and use `classpath:` as a prefix.